# Select Join two tables in mysql with a count/group on both

Tags: mysql, join, count

I'm just learning how to select from two tables with a where clause to match records using one field. So far I can do so using a group/count on on OR the other table e.g.

```
Select count(*),t1.*,t2.all 
from t1,t2 
where t1.Name=t2.name 
group by T1.date 
having count(*)>1
```

OR

```
Select count(*),t1.*,t2.all 
from t1,t2 
where t1.Name=t2.name 
group by T2.order 
# having count(*)>1
```

But I can't do it where both counts>1 (or any other # I choose).

I tried doing table.count(*) e.g.

```
Select t1.count(*),t1.*,t2.all 
from t1,t2 
where t1.Name=t2.name 
group by T1.date 
having count(*)>1
```

but mysql throws an error.  Essentially I'd like to give various count requirements between table to get reports, just one count wont' work.

Here is a sql fiddle with count query from table1, count from table2 and looking for one that counts from both and one that gets ALL recods in Table2 where Table1 count > (notes in sqlfiddle)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c00d2/6

Comment: As an update to make life easier I ran and stored counts in Table2 so I could just query those but it would be nice to know if this is possible for future user.

Comment: You might want to throw some sample data and desired results into your question.  As written, its difficult to understand your requirements.  When using aggregate methods such as `count`, you should define which fields you are aggregating against.  Mysql is a little looser than other databases and allows some syntax with unintended results usually.

Comment: as @sgeddes wisely suggests, give a sqlfiddle or the like, so we can optimize this

Comment: @sgeddes thanks and added as per your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You should read about `JOIN` and avoid using `FROM t1, t2`.

So your last query written properly I guess should be something like:

```
SELECT count(t1.id),
     t1.*,
     t2.all 
FROM t2
LEFT JOIN t1 
ON t1.Name=t2.name 
GROUP BY T1.date 
HAVING count(t1.id)>1
```